# select statement within select

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a `manage` column in my `user` table which contains a string `'2','3','4','5','6'`, these numbers reference the `user.id`'s that the user "manages" .

**STATMENT:**

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN(SELECT manage FROM user WHERE id = 1)
```

***Question:*** *Why is my statement returning nothing?*

Comment: Can you provide the schema for `user` (even if its just id and manage)?  It sounds like `manage` is a string column that contains '2,3,4,5,6'.

Comment: Because a user `id` that is an integer, say `2` is not equal to the `"'2','3','4','5','6'"` string.

Comment: @joncloud yea exactly the `manage` is just a string containing the `id`'s that the user manages (role system)

Comment: @zerkms when I run `SELECT * FROM user WHERE id IN('2','3','4','5','6')` which works fine isn't that a string?

Comment: `IN ('2','3','4','5','6')` is not surely a string, it's a list of strings.

Comment: Normalise your schema, or don't bother with an RDBMS

Comment: @zerkms yea your right, anyway to separate?

Comment: @JordanDavis any reason to join them into a string at all?

Comment: @zerkms only reason is so I don't have to create another pointless table containing two columns and an id.

Comment: @JordanDavis so, how the current "design" is not pointless then, if it does not even work?

Comment: @zerkms its just another table that has to be managed I'd personally rather do in in PHP but just annoying I have to `implode()` and `explode()` every time looking for away around

Comment: @JordanDavis I tend to think one must learn the relation DBs *before* they are allowed to design something, so that someone that supports your "design" after you was not depressed by how terrible the DB schema is.

Comment: @zerkms haha yea yea I hear you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a new table `user_manages`, which contains two columns: `manager_id` and `user_id`.  Create a new record in the table for each user a manager manages.  Then you could develop a join between the two tables.

```
SELECT user.* FROM user_manages
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = user_manages.user_id
WHERE user_manages.manager_id = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`in` works on *lists* of values, not a single string value.  So, if you have a value like so `val in ('1,2,3')` is the asme as `val = '1,2,3'`.

Storing multiple values in a single column is a bad idea for many reasons:

- MySQL's string functions are not particularly powerful.
- Integers should be stored as numbers, not strings.
- A column should only contain one value.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly defined.
- Queries using the "list-in-a-string" column cannot use indexes.

The proper solution is a separate table, called a junction table.

Sometimes, alas, we are stuck with other people's bad design decisions.

If so, you can use `find_in_set()`:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user u
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u2 WHERE u2.id = 1 AND find_in_set(u.id, u2.manage) > 0);
```

Note:  This assumes that the string is comma-delimited with no spaces or quotes.  You may need to use `replace()` to get the string in the right format.

Comment: Was just gonna suggest `find_in_set`